# homebrew configuration issues with python@2

Tags: homebrew

Sorry, I have limited experience with homebrew. Homebrew was working perfectly for a long time but suddenly I was seeing some unexpected errors in my homebrew so I ran brew doctor and I am not sure what to do next. I tried reinstalling python@2 but that did not work either. How do I get things back on track?

```
bigmac:bin michael$ brew doctor
...

Warning: Some installed kegs have no formulae!
This means they were either deleted or installed with `brew diy`.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  python@2

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/async.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asyncerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bioerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf_asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf_no-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bnerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffererr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmserr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comperr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conferr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cryptoerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ct.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cterr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  ...

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  git-ftp

Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may not receive
updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the default branch with:
  git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/cask) checkout master

Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> /Users/bierman/.bash_profile
```